should really need to extract the member to another class
I have several classes for draw chart,
class ChartBase {
private:
   int transparency; //chart attribute
};
class XYChart : public ChartBase{
private:
  std::string xAxis;
  std::string yAxis;
};
class LineChart : public XYChart
{
private:
  int lineWidth;
  int lineColor;
};

and then for some reason refactor the code and extract chart attribute to another classes, and the chartBase has a pointer to new class
class StyleBase {
private:
  int transparency;
};
class XYStyle : public StyleBase {
private:
  std::string xAxis;
  std::string yAxis;
};
class LineStyle : public XYStyle {
private:
  int lineWidth;
  int lineColor;
};

class ChartBase {
protected:
  std::shared_ptr<StyleBase> style;
};

the design has some issues

in derived class such as LineChart, if want to do some thing with lineWidth, color then need to cast the style pointer to LineStyle to access lineWidth, lineColor attribute.
each ChartBase derived class in its constructor will create an instance of StyleBase as bellow

class ChartBase{
public:
  ChartBase() { style = new StyleBase;}
};
class XYChart : public ChartBase{
public:
   XYChart() {style = new XYStyle;}
};
class LineChart : public XYChart {
public:
   LineChart() { style = new LineStyle;}
};

the style constructor in base class is not necessary in case, but in XYChart is necessary, we used XYChart directly in some place.
is there any better design? or we should not extract them from chart?

Chart members must be inside their dedicated Chart class. Your issues arise because you mixed eveything up. Chart classes need their members but their are stored somewhere else, leading to so much boilerplate. Inheritance is not meant to be used like that. Each class is responsible to itself only.

Can you write down your use case in textual format? That will better help understand what you are trying to achieve.

Moreover, your StyleBase class is not polymorphic, so you cannot access derived instances through a pointer (or reference) to the base class.

"...and then for some reason refactor .." What was that "some reason" ? Your initial design looks ok, why did you start to move away from it?

the reason is want to keep each chart's status such as linewidth, color after user manually changed its color, linewdith, and then we can recover its original color,linewidth and etc. so some guys suggest do the change in this way. my first thought use pattern like Memento pattern for this.
